# What is the best way to store Flickr's Shapefiles Public Dataset in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: shapefile, data, sql-server

I'm wanting to import specific locations from the Flickr Shapefile Dataset into SQL Server would like to know what is the best way to store the data in SQL Server 2008?

Link the the 1.0 Dataset: http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/05/21/flickr-shapefiles-public-dataset-10/

Answer (score 6):

flickr shapefiles are plain shp file (if I'm not mistaken) so they can be imported into SQL Server 2008 with few commercial applications like SAFE FME, Manifold, AutoCAD Map etc.
But if you don't have such application available, you can try with this tool [shp2sqlserver](http://code.google.com/p/cumberland/wiki/shp2sqlserver). I didn't try it but it should work. I use [SQL Server 2008 Spatial Tools](http://www.sharpgis.net/2007/12/23/ShapefileToSqlServer2008ToWPF.aspx) but for some reason link doesn't work.
I hope this helps.